# Guardar una foto de perfil almacenada en una base de datos en una variable SESSION y mostrarla

Tags: php, mysqli

Intenté hacerlo de esa manera pero me da `eror`

```
$consulta="Select * from usuario where nickname='$usuario' and pass='$pass2'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

 $_SESSION["foto"] = $row["foto_perfil"];

$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];

$ruta = "../subidos/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name']; 
            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
```

Comment: ¿ Qué error le muestra ?

Comment: más bien no es error solo no me aparece la imagen y al muestro con este código

Comment: <li><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION["foto"] ?>" alt="" id="img"></li>

Comment: quedaria asi <li><img src="../subidos/<?php echo $_SESSION["foto"] ?>" alt="" id="img"></li>

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que es una ruta valida? Seria bueno hacer un dump de lo que tiene $_SESSION["foto"] y estar seguros de que si tiene algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en el `src` estas apuntando solo al nombre de la imagen deberias de poner el `path` donde almacenas la imagen, quedando asi:

```
<li><img src="../subidos/<?php echo $_SESSION["foto"] ?>" alt="" id="img"></li>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada!! Saludos